# Help identify the trim piece behind the front tire on a Mountaineer

Tags: part-identification, mercury, trim

Our 2004 Mountaineer is missing a trim piece behind the right front wheel.  The same piece on the left side:

[image]

and the empty space on the right:

[image]

I've tried to find a replacement part, but without knowing what it's *called* (all sensible keyword combinations have failed me on multiple parts sites), I'm stumped. Any information -- from correct name to a part number -- would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Ford has a [parts resource web site](https://parts.ford.com/shop/en/us/parts/2004/mercury/mountaineer) that appears to have the parts and the references, but as so many things internet, some of the results are obscured by too much detail.

It appears that you are seeking an apron or related front panel per a [page on the above site](https://parts.ford.com/shop/en/us/other-body-related-parts-front/plate-assy-front-fender-apron-6266791-1).

The best I can determine is that the part number is 16C274, but I can be incorrect about that. There's no scale reference other than the wheel arch and the part number doesn't seem to change from left to right side, which is clearly incorrect.

There is a pop-up chat feature on the above site, which may provide yet another level of verification of the correct part.

Comment: More than likely Ford has obsoleted those body parts, they will have to be found aftermarket. Ford begins obsoleting parts after 5 years of age, but i amazes me you can still buy some parts for a 65 mustang.

Comment: That sort of trim along the lower edge of doors or fenders is often called "cladding." OTOH, I spent some time on the Ford parts resource web site above (it was interesting), and like fred_dot_u also didn't find the part.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "2004 Mountaineer fender cladding right" on eBay and was presented with [this part](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mercury-FORD-OEM-02-05-Mountaineer-Fender-Cladding-Right-1L2Z16A038EA/321937618500?fits=Year%3A2004%7CModel%3AMountaineer&epid=1241296153&hash=item4af4fa3644:g:x9AAAOSwSlRa3vFn&vxp=mtr), which I think is what you're looking for. The eBay page says the original Ford part number is 1L2Z16A038EA.